# Running a Javascript Array through a For loop

Tags: javascript

So I'm in the process of completing my codeacademy Javascript curriculum. In this particular problem I'm running an array through a for loop and using one sentence (5 different times) with each  array item. I can't tell what's wrong with my syntax, but it's saying `ReferenceError:` `Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`

```
var names = ["Princilla, Afia, Tenesha, Marissa, Kalimah"];

for (i = 0; i < names.length; 1++) {
    console.log("I know someone called" + names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A postfix operator is an operator (in this case, `++`) that is placed after the operand (in this case, `1`) on which it performs an operation. This error message is telling you that the value you are using as an operand is invalid.

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < names.length; 1++)
```

Should be this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
```

You want to increment the value of the `i` variable. You can't change the value of 1!

In addition, your array elements (or, in this case, element) probably aren't what you want them to be (as per [Frits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050307/1043198)).

Comment: Thanks Ant P. That correction did the trick. I knew it was something simple I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
var names = ["Princilla, Afia, Tenesha, Marissa, Kalimah"];
```

should be:

```
var names = ["Princilla", "Afia", "Tenesha", "Marissa", "Kalimah"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a constant for postfix addition: `1++`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with array you defined and also with `1++`

**Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/zWh2S/**

JS:-

```
var names = ["Princilla", "Afia", "Tenesha", "Marissa", "Kalimah"];

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   console.log("I know someone called " + names[i]);
}
```